# StoreData even phone rebooted

Tags: android, sql, string, store

My app has this appearance

[image]

It seems to be a TableLayout with several TableRows. In my activity, each TableRow has 3 views: ImageView, TextView and a Button.

The user is the one who sets the content of the ImageView and the TestView by entering the text he wants and pressing a button.

I store this data in stringArray variables and works fine if the phone is not restarted or the app is not closed (forceClose)

If one of these two situations happen, i lose all my data.

I've been trying to store my StringArrays by SharedPreferences but I don't know when i should load the preferences, whether it's in OnCreate() or OnResume() or OnStart methods().

Another question is how to define the arrays. I use this:

String[] titulo = new String[500];

I don't know if this string is created each time i start the activity. Because what i want is to load the previous String (from SharedPreferences) and add some more entries not to create new ones every time the phone is rebooted, for example.

Do you think i need a SQL database or it's OK with this StringArrays.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably switch to using a database, seeing as you have an array of size 500, which could possibly increase in the future.

However, if you want to continue using SharedPreferences, you should write the data in onPause() and onStop() methods, and use an if else statement to see if your data is null before running an operation on it. If the data is null, the read it from the SharedPreferences before continuing.

Comment: Thank you. I think I'll create a database.